# Trying to resize my logo & add a title to the side of the logo without resizing the navbar

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to resize my logo & add a title to the side of the logo without resizing the navbar. 
[What the current navbar looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBxKp.png)

**HTML:**

```
<header id="header">
<img src="logohtml.png" alt="logo" id="header-img">
  <nav id="nav-bar">
    <ul> 
           <li><a class="nav-link" href="#"><b>Things to Do</b></a></li>
           <li><a class="nav-link" href="#"><b>Where to Eat</b></a></li>
           <li><a class="nav-link" href="#"><b>Events</b></a></li>
           <li><a class="nav-link" href="#"><b>Hotels</b></a></li> 
       <li><a class="nav-link" href="#"><b>Parking</b></a></li> 
    </ul>  
  </nav>
```

**CSS:**

```
header {
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #FFAA63;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Exo 2', sans-serif;
    padding: 1em;
    width: 100%
}

header::after {
    clear: both;
    content: '';
    display: table;
}

#header-img {
    width: 90px;
    height: 50px;
    float: left;
    padding-top: 1.7em;
}
```

**EDIT:**

This is the navbar after applying your code. The logo is still the same size for some reason. I would like it to be bigger but not change the height of the navbar.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pyJFk.png)

**EDIT:** 
I did as suggested & my logo fits into the navbar, thank you!
I added width & played around with the height & width.

```
#header-img {
  position: absolute;
  height: 160px;
  width: 250px;
}
```

[Current navbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHFUT.png)

Comment: Your code lacks the styles for list items and logo image to properly try to give a suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my assumption of what your provided code lacked. I built your navbar like the following snippet, I hope it will help you somehow.

Basically, my solution used `flexbox` applied to the header in order to let elements of header to display in row. then using `align-items: center` to vertically align and `justify-content: space-between` to create a space between the logo and the navabr.

**Edit:** refer to this link to playaround: https://codepen.io/DohaHelmy/pen/xxbzzRN

I tried to re-position the logo and added a name next to it. also consider removing `margin-top` added to the header as it is just set to show the effect properly.

For better display of the result run the snippet using **full page**

```css
header {
  margin-top: 50px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #ffaa63;
  color: white;
  font-family: "Exo 2", sans-serif;
  padding: 1em;
  width: 100%;
}

#logo{
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   font-size: 35px;
   position: relative;
}

#logo span{
   position: relative;
   left: 220px;
}

#header-img {
  position: absolute;
  height: 120px;
}

#nav-bar ul {
  position: relative;
  right: 50px;
  list-style-type: none;
  overflow: auto;
}

#nav-bar ul li {
  float: left;
  margin: 0px 20px;
  color: #fff;
}

#nav-bar .nav-link {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<header id="header">
   <div id="logo">
      <img src="https://www.freepnglogos.com/uploads/eagles-png-logo/eagle-sports-png-logos--0.png" alt="logo" id="header-img">
   <span>Logo name</span>
   </div>
  
  <nav id="nav-bar">
    <ul>
      <li><a class="nav-link" href="#"><b>Things to Do</b></a></li>
      <li><a class="nav-link" href="#"><b>Where to Eat</b></a></li>
      <li><a class="nav-link" href="#"><b>Events</b></a></li>
      <li><a class="nav-link" href="#"><b>Hotels</b></a></li>
      <li><a class="nav-link" href="#"><b>Parking</b></a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Thank you, for your help! Your reference is exactly how I want my navbar to look. I put your code in & the logo is the same size. Would it help if I provided the whole code for my HTML & CSS? I'm not sure what else to do. Thanks again!

Comment: If my answer solved your problem. no need to add anything. It is just better to provide a minimal code with exactly the same bug you had for people to offer better solutions. Anyway, don't forget to upvote and accept my answer if it works well with you ^^

Comment: Unfortunately, your code didn't work the logo is still the same size. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @patrice123 ok I did edited my answer. I hope it helps. if not please edit your question with an illustration of what needed to prevent conflicts.

Comment: Sure, I have added an image of the current navbar after adding your code. I'm not sure why the logo isn't any bigger. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @patrice123 this code is for the logo image `#header-img {
  position: absolute;
  height: 120px;
}` , increasing the height of the image and positioning it to absolute to prevent changing the height of the navbar. find where to add the code it should work well.

Comment: Thank you! I followed your advise & played around with the #header-img tag adding width to the code as well.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't quite understand your question but I think you need to move the logo to the right side a bit without affecting the size of the navbar. Or maybe you want to resize the logo but without affecting the navbar. So this solution works for both problems.

```
#nav-bar {
left: 58%;
position: absolute;
margin-top: 30px; }
```

Comment: Sorry about that, thank you for your suggestion. I wanted my logo to remain where it is on my navbar but make it a little bigger. I've been trying to tweak it but when I do I end up making the navbar bigger.